# python open function trunctating output

Tags: python, file-writing, truncation, truncated

I am very new to python and coding in general, so any help or point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to print an output to a file using python's open function. when I print the 'jstat_output' variable to the terminal it appears fine, but when I try to read the textfile it has been truncated.

the code:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'w', newline='') as o:
for item in jstat_output:
    o.write(f'{item}\n')
```

terminal output:

```
[Container(PayloadLength=81, Payload=u'  S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   '), Container(PayloadLength=81, Payload=u'  S0     S1     E      O      M     CCS    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   ')]
```

notepad viewer:

> Container:
> PayloadLength = 81
> Payload = u'  S0     S1     E      O      M '... (truncated, total 81)
> Container:
> PayloadLength = 81
> Payload = u'  S0     S1     E      O      M '... (truncated, total 81)

if anyone knows why this happens, or perhaps a different method to write to a file it would be a massive help; thanks.

```
    for pid in extracted_numbers:
        exec_resp = ecs.execute_command(
            cluster=f'{clusterArn[0]}',
            container=f'{containerNames[ttype]}',
            task=f'{tArns[tarn]}',
            command=f'jstat -gcutil {pid} 250',
            interactive=True
    )
    session = exec_resp['session']
    connection = websocket.create_connection(session['streamUrl'])
    try:
        init_payload = {
            "MessageSchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "RequestId": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "TokenValue": session['tokenValue']
        }
        connection.send(json.dumps(init_payload))

        AgentMessageHeader = c.Struct(
            'HeaderLength' / c.Int32ub,
            'MessageType' / c.PaddedString(32, 'ascii'),
        )

        AgentMessagePayload = c.Struct(
            'PayloadLength' / c.Int32ub,
            'Payload' / c.PaddedString(c.this.PayloadLength, 'ascii')
        )

        while True:
            response = connection.recv()

            message = AgentMessageHeader.parse(response)

            if 'channel_closed' in message.MessageType:
                raise Exception('Channel closed before command output was received')

            if 'output_stream_data' in message.MessageType:
                break
    finally:
        connection.close()

    payload_message = AgentMessagePayload.parse(response[message.HeaderLength:])
    jstat_output.append(payload_message)

print(jstat_output)
with open(path_to_file, openvar, newline='') as o:
    print(f'{jstat_output}', file=o)
```

this is the portion of the code that is related to the problem.

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't print anything.  Can you include the part where you do the printing?

Comment: through trial and error, i've come to see that it has something to do with the for loop. when i remove the for loop it works. i'd like to keep the for loop so if anyone knows how to accomplish this i'd really be grateful for the help.

Comment: It looks like the terminal output doesn't match the default string representation of `Container` so I expect you're doing something extra with your `print()` call to make it print the full contents.  Seeing that code would help.  Seeing the definition of `Container` might also suggest an easier solution.

Comment: @yaniv Remove `file=o`

Comment: @Cardstdani What? Why? That's fine.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your `print()` prints the non-truncated version is that it's printing the `repr()` of each item instead of the `str()` of it.

I believe this will do what you want:

```
with open(path_to_file, 'w') as o:
    for item in jstat_output:
        o.write(repr(item) + "\n")
```

The clue is that `jstat_output` is a list and when you printed it with:

```
print(jstat_output)
```

you got the desired output.

When a list is rendered as a string, it renders the `repr()` of each of its individual items.  If the items are formatted individually (e.g. by doing  `f"{item}"` or `print(item)`), you're instead getting their `str()` representation.  In this case, the `str()` representation is truncated when the item is large, whereas `repr()` includes the whole thing.  Explicitly calling `repr(item)` instead of using an f-string should therefore get you the output you're looking for.  You could also still use an f-string as long as you put the `repr()` inside the `{}`, i.e. `f"{repr(item)}\n"`.

A better solution might be to write your own function to output a `Container` in the desired format rather than relying on its `__repr__` implementation, but that would require being able to see the definition of the `Container` class.

Comment: Or `f"{item!r}"`.

Comment: this worked! thank you, I didn't know that rendering a list as a string would create this issue.